# Spring Data MongoDB @Indexed(unique = true) in inner field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

For example, there are 2 classes:

```
@Document
public class WordSet {
   @Id
   private ObjectId id;

   private Language language;
   private ObjectId languageId;
} 

@Document
public class Language {
   @Id
   private ObjectId id;

   @Index(unique = true)
   private String languageName;
}
```

Languages are stored in separate collection and WordSets are stored in another collection. BUT WordSet is stored only with languageId (language is always null when I save WordSet). language field in WordSet is needed, but it retrieved using aggregation

```
public Flux<WordSet> getAll() {
        AggregationOperation[] joinLanguages = new AggregationOperation[] {
                lookup(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Language.class), "languageId", "_id", "language"),
                unwind("language")
        };

        Aggregation agg = newAggregation(joinLanguages);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, WordSet.class, WordSet.class);
    }
```

So, WordSet in mongodb contains only languageId and language field is filled using aggregation (join from Language collection).

But if I want to add more than one WordSet to collection I have an error 
com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: langdope.wordSet index: language.language_name_index dup key: { : null }

How can I handle it? I need languageName to be unique, but also I want to save objects which contains Languages without this problems. I can't just mark language as @Transient (aggregation will not work).

Comment: As I can see, spring creates index for field "language.languageName" in WordSet collection.... I don't know how to disable it